# How do I indicate that there are available code / hover actions in the sign column of NeoVim

Tags: neovim

I am using `rust-tools` and everything is working fine with inlay hints, diagnostics etc. The code actions are also working fine in that when I call the dialog on a line I get the options and can apply them just fine. The only issue is that I don't know when a code action is available so I would like to add something in the sign column that indicates the presence of available hover actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nvim-lightbulb](https://github.com/kosayoda/nvim-lightbulb) for this which shows up a little lightbulb in the sign-column like in IntelliJ if you can apply some actions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did see this but on a first try it didn't work for me and was looking for setting it manually. If there is no answer I will accept this though 

Comment: Does the plugin still doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Dionysis do you still need some help to make the plugin work?

Comment: I haven't had time to check yet so we shall see  I am sure it will be a matter of tweaking the setup. Thank you for offering to help!

Comment: No problem, if you've got a problem, just ask it here or create an issue on its github-page. I'm sure that someone will help you. Happy vimming! c(^-^)c